# How can the following non-convex problem be converted to a convex one?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima, discriminant

Minimize: $x^2+xy+3y^2-x-4y+1$

Subject to: $(x-1)\log(1+\exp(x))\leq 0, x+y\geq0$

Comment: Can you convert your constraint on $x$ to a simpler constraint?

Comment: @Michael That is the point I am asking for. The nonconvexity of the problem is because of that constraint.

Comment: So what have you done?  For what values of $x$ does the cosntraint hold?  For what values of $x$ is $\log(1+e^x)\leq 0$? Can you plot the function for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find a maximal value of $k$, for which the inequality
$$x^2+xy+3y^2-x-4y+1\geq k$$ is true for all reals $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y\geq0$ and $x\leq1.$

We have $$3y^2+(x-4)y+x^2-x+1-k\geq0,$$ for which we need
$$(x-4)^2-12(x^2-x+1-k)\leq0$$ or
$$11x^2-4x-4-12k\geq0,$$ for which we need
$$4-11(-4-12k)\leq0$$ or
$$k\leq-\frac{4}{11}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y)=\left(\frac{2}{11},\frac{7}{11}\right)$ and we see that the condition holds.

Thus, $-\frac{4}{11}$ is a minimal value of our expression.

Comment: Congratulation on your $\lceil$ **BRONZE ! ! ! discriminant tag badge** $\rfloor$